# SQS Single Request Processing with Multiple Messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to find a document of how requests will be processed if there is some network error between request from Client -> AWS SQS?

Because if one request can contain up to 10 messages, how would it work if there is an http error on the request while the 10 messages are being processed to SQS? Does SQS fail the whole request, and all 10 messages are being re-published? OR some messages get processed, and we will reprocess the whole thing again (which will have some duplication)?

I am trying to determine if I can cut cost with aggregating messages into 1 single request, but wonder if this will hurt idempotency.

Answer (score 2):

So when you're sending messages as batch you'll be processing it one by one so each message will have its unique receipthandle so you've delete each message programmatically after processing it to avoid duplication

Comment: Sorry could you explain this? `when you're sending messages as batch you'll be processing it one by one ` - are you basically saying to send single message/request to do receipthandle? Or are you saying when sending 10 message/request, SQS has a receipthandle to not accept the same message? Also processing as in an SQS Client Publisher processing, or we have to build a publisher that does this?